# Magento order custom status

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, sales

How to get custom order status in frontend

We are using Marketplace in our site in that seller can able to processes order through front end. Now i added custom status as Shipment how to call this to frontend while seller click shipment order status also need to change

Same like i created a custom order status called shipment

Controller File

```
public function saveTrackingNumberAction(){
        try{
            if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
                $orderid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
                $trackingid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('tracking_id');
                $carrier=$this->getRequest()->getParam('carrier');
                $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
                $items=array();
                $shippingAmount=0;
                $trackingsdata=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                                 ->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                                 ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($itemid);
                foreach($trackingsdata as $tracking){
                    $tracking->setTrackingNumber($trackingid);
                    $tracking->setCarrierName($carrier);
                    $tracking->save();
                    $product_name="";
                    $shippingAmount=$tracking->getShippingCharges();
                    $items=explode(',',$tracking->getItemIds());
                    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
                        if(in_array($item->getId(),$items)){
                            $product_name =$product_name.$product->getName()." ,";
                        }
                    }

                    $product_name = $product->getName();
                    $to = $order->getCustomerEmail();

                    $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('trackingnopartner');
                    $emailTempVariables = array();              
                    $adminEmail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $product_name;
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $trackingid;
                    $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);
                    $emailTemp->setSenderName('Admin');
                    $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                    $emailTemp->send($to,'Admin',$emailTempVariables);
                }

                    /**/
                $itemsarray = $this->_getItemQtys($order,$items);

                if(count($itemsarray)>0){
                    if($order->canInvoice()) { 
                        $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($itemsarray['data']);
                        $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
                        $invoice->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
                        $invoice->setSubtotal($itemsarray['subtotal']);
                        $invoice->setBaseSubtotal($itemsarray['baseSubtotal']);
                        $invoice->setGrandTotal($itemsarray['subtotal']+$shippingAmount);
                        $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($itemsarray['subtotal']+$shippingAmount);
                        $invoice->register();

                        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                    ->addObject($invoice)
                                    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
                        $transactionSave->save();
                        $order->sendNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment(
                            Mage::helper('mpshippingmanager')->__('Notified customer about invoice #%s.', $invoice->getId())
                        )
                        ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
                        ->save();
                        $seller_invoice_id = $invoice->getId();
                    }else{
                        if($order->hasInvoices()) {
                            foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) { 
                                foreach ($inv->getAllItems() as $item) { 
                                    $product_id = $item->getProductId();
                                    $seller_pro_coll=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                                                            ->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$product_id))
                                                            ->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                                    foreach ($seller_pro_coll as $value) {
                                        if($value->getMageproductid()){
                                            $seller_invoice_id = $inv->getId();
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    $shipment = false;              
                    $shipmentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id');         
                    $orderId = $orderid;    
                    if($shipmentId){
                        $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentId);
                    }elseif($orderId){
                        $order  = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
                        if (!$order->getId()) {
                            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order no longer exists.'));
                            return false;
                        }
                        if($order->getForcedDoShipmentWithInvoice()){
                            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot do shipment for the order separately from invoice.'));
                            return false;
                        }
                        if(!$order->canShip()){
                            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot do shipment for the order.'));
                            return false;
                        }

                        $savedQtys = $this->_getItemQtys($order,$items);
                        $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($savedQtys['data']);
                    }
                    $shipment->register();
                    $comment = '';
                    $shipment->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(1);
                    $responseAjax = new Varien_Object();
                    $isNeedCreateLabel = isset($data['create_shipping_label']) && $data['create_shipping_label'];
                    if ($isNeedCreateLabel && true) {
                        $responseAjax->setOk(true);
                    }
                    $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
                    $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                ->addObject($shipment)->addObject($shipment->getOrder())->save();
                    /*sale list status update*/
                    $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
                    $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid', array('eq' => $partnerid))
                                ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid', array('eq' => $orderid));
                    foreach($collection as $saleproduct){
                        $saleproduct->setCpprostatus(1);
                        $saleproduct->save();
                    }
                    /*sale list status update*/
                    $shipment->sendEmail(1, $comment);
                    $shipmentCreatedMessage = $this->__('The shipment has been created.');
                    $labelCreatedMessage    = $this->__('The shipping label has been created.');
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($isNeedCreateLabel ? $shipmentCreatedMessage . ' ' . $labelCreatedMessage
                        : $shipmentCreatedMessage); 

                    $trackingcol1=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                ->addFieldtoFilter('seller_id ',array('in'=>$partnerid));
                    $courrier="custom";
                    foreach($trackingcol1 as $row) {
                        if($shipment->getId() != '') { 
                            $row->setShipmentId($shipment->getId());
                            $row->setInvoiceId($seller_invoice_id)->save();
                            $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                             ->setShipment($shipment)
                             ->setData('title',  $row->getCarrierName())
                             ->setData('number', $row->getTrackingNumber())
                             ->setData('carrier_code',  $courrier)
                             ->setData('order_id', $shipment->getData('order_id'))
                             ->save();
                        }
                    }
                }
                $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>''));
                if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                    $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>'canceled'));
                    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                    if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                        $product_order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
                        $order->setStatus('test'); //**Custom Status**
                        $order->save();
                    }else{
                        $order->cancel();
                        $order->save();
                    }
                    $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                    $historyItem = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
                        ->getUnnotifiedForInstance($order, Mage_Sales_Model_Order::HISTORY_ENTITY_NAME);
                    if ($historyItem) {
                        $historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified(1);
                        $historyItem->save();
                    }       
                }
                if(count($trackingsdata)==0)
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("This order doesn't contain Tracking Number..");
                else
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Tracking Number successfully Assign..');
                $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));
        }
    }
```

.phtml file

```
<?php if($item_status=="Ordered"||$item_status=="Invoiced"){?>
                                                <button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Save Tracking Number') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
                                                    <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Save Tracking Number') ?></span></span>
                                                </button>
                                            <?php } ?>
```

What's wrong on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php if($invoiceId):
?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/order/',array('order_id'=>$mageorderid,'status'=>'shipment'));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php// echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="<?php echo $mageorderid?>" style="float:right;">
        <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span>
    </button></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

just add method in ShippingController.php

```
  public function orderAction()
  {
       echo $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
       echo $status = $this->getRequest()->getParam('status');
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id);
        $order->setData('state', $status);
     $order->setStatus($status);
     $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
     $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
     $order->save(); 
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
            );
             //$this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/index');


 }


public function testAction()
      {
           echo $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
           echo $status = $this->getRequest()->getParam('status');
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id);
            $order->setData('state', $status);
         $order->setStatus($status);
         $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
         $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
         $order->save(); 
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );
                 //$this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/index');


     }
```

Comment: I am asking i already created custom order status Called Shipment how to call in front end to seller dashboard

Comment: sorry don't understand you want the current order status or create status from frontend?

Comment: create custom status from frontend?

Comment: do you have any custom module added?

Comment: add solution with module try that..

Comment: i used this for get custom status in backend

Comment: no this is different module try it..

Comment: ok how to get front end for all custom status

Comment: i added in link add status from there just added the status it will automatically change it

Comment: No it's not display front end

Comment: Already i used mpassignshiiping magaer module

Comment: can you there config and controller file?

Comment: what is not display sorry don't get you?

Comment: i added the code just add in your controller file and also the html code

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: check the updated answer..

Comment: After click shipment i got this error Fatal error: Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46

Comment: can you paste url where it give the error?

Comment: update the code and check the values

Comment: same error Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in

Comment: can you give me test credential so i can check it?

Comment: update the html now there was mistake there.. update it and feedback

Comment: update the html part of my answer..

Comment: after that also same

Comment: update the html your url are not correct....

Comment: your order_id is missing add the order id and your status change will work

Comment: shipment is id or label

Comment: It is custom status

Comment: It showing The order state has been changed. but  it still showing in old state only also redirect to home page

Comment: Add order id in url and add redirect url too in action

Comment: Where i have to add

Comment: Where you are adding order status rto

Comment: while click rto button order status also changed as RTO

Comment: Wait i will update code after    30 min

Comment: Updated html part try that

Comment: Still it it didn't change status

Comment: give me credential let me  check..

Comment: this is order id ? 1503

Comment: this is order id : 100001550

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/order/',array('order_id'=>$mageorderid,'status'=>'shipment'));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php// echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="100001550" style="float:right;">
        <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span>
    </button></a>` add order id here

Comment: update controller function too...

Comment: there are order id  missing you need order id to update order status

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/order/',array('order_id'=>$mageorderid‌​,'status'=>'rto'));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php// echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="100001550" style="float:right;"> <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span> </button></a>

Comment: `$mageorderid‌`​‌​ this must be current order id. kindly replace it with order id

Comment: <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/order/',array('100001550','status'=>'rto'));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php// echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="100001550" style="float:right;"> <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span> </button></a>

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/order/',array('order_id'=>'100001550','status'=>'r‌​to'));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php// echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="100001550" style="float:right;"> <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span> </button></a>` use this code

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ''status'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')'

Comment: `<?php $orderid=100001550; ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/order/',array('order_id'=>$orderid,'status'=>'rto'));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php// echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="<?php echo $mageorderid?>" style="float:right;">
        <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span>
    </button></a>` use this

Comment: again error Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::loadIncrementById(Array
(
    [0] => 1503
)
)

Comment: can you please login and check that

Comment: Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order::loadIncrementById(Array
(
    [0] => 100001550
)
)

Comment: update  the function order there was error. update and check

Comment: status didn't change but it redirect

Comment: is there any error generate?

Comment: NO error after click Shipement it redirect to another page that's it

Comment: is status getting changed?

Comment: No that also not changed

Comment: updated the order code try it is tested code..

Comment: Check my updated question still now it redirect only not change the status

Comment: is cache is disabled.. and try for other order..

Comment: cache is disable only ok i try another order

Comment: Can you please check my updated question Here one button is there once i click it change order status like wise how to add all other custom status

Comment: update the answer for multiple status..

Answer (score 1):

`<?php $orderid=100001550; ?> <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/order/',array('order_id'=>$orderid,'st‌​atus'=>'test'));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php// echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="<?php echo $mageorderid?>" style="float:right;"> <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('test') ?></span></span> </button></a>`

**add it like that**

`<?php $orderid=100001550; ?> <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/order/',array('order_id'=>$orderid,'st‌​atus'=>'somestatus'));?>"><button class="button wk_mp_btn wk_invoiceslip" title="<?php// echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" id="<?php echo $mageorderid?>" style="float:right;"> <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('test') ?></span></span> </button></a>`

**you can add unlimited status.**

Comment: No it's not changeing

Comment: the last code was working to change the status to `rto`

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: this code is generate shipment and add the status. what you want to achieve from this code?

Comment: yes that what i am asking

Comment: code wise i need to change the status from front end as well as back end

Comment: if your status is changed from frontend then it will automatically change the backend.

Comment: add new question with more detail what you want to achieve

Comment: as for i understand you want to create the shipment and change the status too?

Comment: Yes in back end i have custom button and status if i click that button order status also changed so i need that front end also.

Comment: copy that in front controller and pass the values and it will work..

Comment: Which means????

Comment: Create different button if i click button it will chnage status

Comment: no i asking same function will be used on fronted just copy in front controller and pass the order id they will work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32987/discussion-between-kothari-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: if i click Save Tracking Number button it automatically change into complete like that i need 1 button if i click automatically order status chnage into shipement

Comment: i give you code for that...

Comment: How to add a new controller for custom status

Comment: you want to add newController or new method like about `order`?

Comment: method only sorry

Comment: added new method...

Comment: can you please check this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94694/magento-order-status-custom