# Magento Order status custom

Tags: magento-1.9

Once i click save tracking number it automatically generate invoice and order status will be changed complete. check my below code. It's working fine

**Controller file**

```
public function saveTrackingNumberAction(){
            try{
                if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
                    $orderid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
                    $trackingid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('tracking_id');
                    $carrier=$this->getRequest()->getParam('carrier');
                    $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                    $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
                    $items=array();
                    $shippingAmount=0;
                    $trackingsdata=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                                     ->addFieldToFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                                     ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                    $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($itemid);
                    foreach($trackingsdata as $tracking){
                        $tracking->setTrackingNumber($trackingid);
                        $tracking->setCarrierName($carrier);
                        $tracking->save();
                        $product_name="";
                        $shippingAmount=$tracking->getShippingCharges();
                        $items=explode(',',$tracking->getItemIds());
                        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
                            if(in_array($item->getId(),$items)){
                                $product_name =$product_name.$product->getName()." ,";
                            }
                        }

                        $product_name = $product->getName();
                        $to = $order->getCustomerEmail();

                        $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('trackingnopartner');
                        $emailTempVariables = array();              
                        $adminEmail=Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $product_name;
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                        $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $trackingid;
                        $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);
                        $emailTemp->setSenderName('Admin');
                        $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                        $emailTemp->send($to,'Admin',$emailTempVariables);
                    }

                        /**/
                    $itemsarray = $this->_getItemQtys($order,$items);

                    if(count($itemsarray)>0){
                        if($order->canInvoice()) { 
                            $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($itemsarray['data']);
                            $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
                            $invoice->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
                            $invoice->setSubtotal($itemsarray['subtotal']);
                            $invoice->setBaseSubtotal($itemsarray['baseSubtotal']);
                            $invoice->setGrandTotal($itemsarray['subtotal']+$shippingAmount);
                            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($itemsarray['subtotal']+$shippingAmount);
                            $invoice->register();

                            $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                        ->addObject($invoice)
                                        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
                            $transactionSave->save();
                            $order->sendNewOrderEmail()->addStatusHistoryComment(
                                Mage::helper('mpshippingmanager')->__('Notified customer about invoice #%s.', $invoice->getId())
                            )
                            ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
                            ->save();
                            $seller_invoice_id = $invoice->getId();
                        }else{
                            if($order->hasInvoices()) {
                                foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) { 
                                    foreach ($inv->getAllItems() as $item) { 
                                        $product_id = $item->getProductId();
                                        $seller_pro_coll=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                                                                ->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$product_id))
                                                                ->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$partnerid));
                                        foreach ($seller_pro_coll as $value) {
                                            if($value->getMageproductid()){
                                                $seller_invoice_id = $inv->getId();
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        $shipment = false;              
                        $shipmentId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment_id');         
                        $orderId = $orderid;    
                        if($shipmentId){
                            $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipmentId);
                        }elseif($orderId){
                            $order  = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
                            if (!$order->getId()) {
                                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('The order no longer exists.'));
                                return false;
                            }
                            if($order->getForcedDoShipmentWithInvoice()){
                                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot do shipment for the order separately from invoice.'));
                                return false;
                            }
                            if(!$order->canShip()){
                                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot do shipment for the order.'));
                                return false;
                            }

                            $savedQtys = $this->_getItemQtys($order,$items);
                            $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($savedQtys['data']);
                        }
                        $shipment->register();
                        $comment = '';
                        $shipment->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(1);
                        $responseAjax = new Varien_Object();
                        $isNeedCreateLabel = isset($data['create_shipping_label']) && $data['create_shipping_label'];
                        if ($isNeedCreateLabel && true) {
                            $responseAjax->setOk(true);
                        }
                        $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
                        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                                    ->addObject($shipment)->addObject($shipment->getOrder())->save();
                        /*sale list status update*/
                        $partnerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getId();
                        $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid', array('eq' => $partnerid))
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid', array('eq' => $orderid));
                        foreach($collection as $saleproduct){
                            $saleproduct->setCpprostatus(1);
                            $saleproduct->save();
                        }
                        /*sale list status update*/
                        $shipment->sendEmail(1, $comment);
                        $shipmentCreatedMessage = $this->__('The shipment has been created.');
                        $labelCreatedMessage    = $this->__('The shipping label has been created.');
                        $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($isNeedCreateLabel ? $shipmentCreatedMessage . ' ' . $labelCreatedMessage
                            : $shipmentCreatedMessage); 

                        $trackingcol1=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('seller_id ',array('in'=>$partnerid));
                        $courrier="custom";
                        foreach($trackingcol1 as $row) {
                            if($shipment->getId() != '') { 
                                $row->setShipmentId($shipment->getId());
                                $row->setInvoiceId($seller_invoice_id)->save();
                                $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
                                 ->setShipment($shipment)
                                 ->setData('title',  $row->getCarrierName())
                                 ->setData('number', $row->getTrackingNumber())
                                 ->setData('carrier_code',  $courrier)
                                 ->setData('order_id', $shipment->getData('order_id'))
                                 ->save();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>''));
                    if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                        $trackingcol=Mage::getModel('mpshippingmanager/tracking')->getCollection()
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('order_id',array('eq'=>$orderid))
                                    ->addFieldtoFilter('tracking_number',array('eq'=>'canceled'));
                        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                        if(count($trackingcol)==0){
                            $product_order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
                            $order->setStatus('invoice');
                            $order->save();
                        }else{
                            $order->cancel();
                            $order->save();
                        }
                        $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
                        $historyItem = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
                            ->getUnnotifiedForInstance($order, Mage_Sales_Model_Order::HISTORY_ENTITY_NAME);
                        if ($historyItem) {
                            $historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified(1);
                            $historyItem->save();
                        }       
                    }
                    if(count($trackingsdata)==0)
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError("This order doesn't contain Tracking Number..");
                    else
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Tracking Number successfully Assign..');
                    $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));
                }
            }catch(Exception $e){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));
            }
        }
```

**.phtml file**

```
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/savetrackingnumber')?>" id="shipping-form" method="post">
<div class="shipping_top">
<span class="shipping_service"><?php echo $helper->__('Carrier');?></span>
<span class="row_total"><?php echo $helper->__('Tracking Number');?></span>
</div>
<div class="items">
<input class="required-entry" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_order->getId(); ?>" name="order_id"/>
<div class="wk_item">
<span class="carrier"><input class="required-entry carrier" value="<?php echo $tracking->getCarrierName(); ?>" <?php echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="carrier"/></span>
<span class="row_total wk_track_input"><input class="required-entry" value="<?php echo $tracking->getTrackingNumber(); ?>" <?php echo $disabled;?> type="text" name="tracking_id"/></span>
<?php if(count($shipping_coll)): ?>
<?php if($item_status=="Ordered"): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/cancelorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
<button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel Order') ?></span></span>
</button>
</a>
<?php endif;  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($item_status=="Ordered"||$item_status=="Invoiced"){?>
<button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Save Tracking Number') ?>" type="submit" id="save_butn" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Save Tracking Number') ?></span></span>
</button>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Now i change **Complete** into **invoice**  it also working fine but after that i add custom order status called shipement if i click shipement order status automatically change into complete. But it should change shipement what is the problem.

Custom Method

```
public function shipementorderAction()
{
    $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
    $order->setData('state', 'shipement');
    $order->setStatus('shipement');
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save(); 

    $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);

    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
        $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
    );
    //$this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/index');
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully'); $this->_redirectReferer();


}
```

**.phtml**

```
 <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpshippingmanager/shipping/shipementorder',array('id'=>$mageorderid))?>">
<button class="button wk_mp_btn" style="flaot:none" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?>" type="button" id="save_butn" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Shipment') ?></span></span>
</button>
</a>
```

Comment: are you facing this issue only order view page or order listing page?

Comment: While Click save Tracking Number it automatically change order status Complete i want to change invoiced and one more button if i click status change into shipement

Answer (score 0):

use this for creating the invoice

```
     public function saveTrackingNumberAction(){

                     $orderid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');

   $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
     try {
           if(!$order->canInvoice())
           {

           }else {

           $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();

           if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
              $error=true;

           }else {

           $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
           $invoice->register();
           $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
           ->addObject($invoice)
           ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

           $transactionSave->save();
           $sucess=true;

              $order->setData('state', 'invoice');
              $order->setStatus('invoice');
              $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);


              $history->setIsCustomerNotified(true);
              $invoice->sendEmail(true, '');

              $order->save();


        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Tracking Number successfully Assign..');
                $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));


           }}
        }
     catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {

        }}
```

use this code to create shipment
   simple create the shipment

```
public function shipementorderAction()
    {  
    $orderid=$this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
      $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
   if($order->canShip())
{
$itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQty);
$shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
$shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId);
 $order->setData('state', 'shipment');
          $order->setStatus('shipment');
          $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);


          $history->setIsCustomerNotified(true);
          $shipment->sendEmail(true, '');

          $order->save();


    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Tracking Number successfully Assign..');
            $this->_redirect('mpshippingmanager/shipping/invoice/id/',array('id'=>$orderid));

}}
```

Comment: While Click save Tracking Number it automatically change order status Complete i want to change invoiced and one more button if i click status change into shipement

Comment: you are put the code there for change the status to invoice that are not working?

Comment: Ya it change into invoiced but i have one more button shipement if i click it change into complete

Comment: it should change shipement only bt it changed complete

Comment: on shipmentorder action your are talking about?

Comment: Yes both shipmentorder and savetrackingnumber

Comment: what status you want for tracking number and shipment?

Comment: tracking number - invoiced and Shipement - Shipement

Comment: $order->setStatus('invoice'); it's working but if i click shipement button it automatically complete insted of shipement

Comment: Whenever i click save tracking number button in back end Comments History it shows complete

Comment: i don't know what is the problem

Comment: what is the problem what mistake ?

Comment: update the code for invoice.

Comment: your code is automatically create and invoice and shipment to so creating the shipment the magento set the state by default complete..

Comment: after that code it redirect to blank page & invoice also not generate

Comment: add redirection too

Comment: where i have to add also invoice not generated

Comment: any error generated??

Comment: No error it redirect to blank page after that i go back status is changed but invoice not generated. then i click shipement also changed complete

Comment: add the status code for shipment too

Comment: Now status changed but invoice not generated also i click shipement button it shows error order_not_exists

Comment: updated the answer and kindly try with new order for invoice..

Comment: No luck status only changed rest of the thing not working

Comment: check the error log for error..

Comment: while customer place order that time new order pending, then admin approve order that time order status processing, if seller click invoice button that time invoiced and shipement time it shows shipement

Comment: No error????????

Comment: check the backend this code is working because it is working code i use in my project so i have no issue with that

Comment: In back end also showing invoice only but shipment not working. i need to generate invoice front end

Comment: in backend invoice generated but front end it's not showing pdf

Comment: @Qaisair i found this code only complete the staus $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')       ->addObject($shipment)->addObject($shipment->getOrder())->save(); and generate the invoice so plz tell me how to change this. State should be invoiced and invoice slip should be generated

Comment: `$shipment->getOrder()->setState('invoice');` add this because this code set the state in process and change this line and check..

Comment: I already check but shipement changed complete status

Comment: you have to change the default states from admin panel..

Comment: Which means?????

Comment: `system-> order statuses` in admin panel they are set by default change from there..

Comment: How to change that can you please tell me

Comment: How to change that order status

Comment: I on mobile phone i will update you ĺater

Comment: What is the problem how to change order status?

Comment: read this http://www.magestore.com/manage-magento-online-store/magento-order-status-and-magento-order-state

Comment: i need to unassign complete state

Comment: yes you need to unassigned the state

Comment: Now also same after click order status is completed only

Comment: refresh cache and see

Comment: No luck still now complete only